# How to plot an excel file in matlab

Tags: matlab, xlsread

Assume that I imported a 703*778 excel file into matlab workspace as a .mat file. Now,say I want to plot these data excluding the datas from two particular rows,say 250th & 500th row.The excel data is purely numerical.Here is the code that I tried:

```
data = xlsread('A.xlsx','Sheet1','');

b    = data(A2:ACX249,A251:ACX499,A501:ACX778);

plot(b);
```

The 778 columns are named from A through ACX.

Where I have gone wrong with this code?

Comment: Don't you want a 3D plot? With so many Y data, I would think so.

Comment: No I would not be requiring a 3-D plot. Could you please tell where I have gone wrong with the code mentioned in the Question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you should look into 3D plot such as `surf`. Assume your 703-by-778 matrix is stored in variable `data` then

```
figure;
subplot(1,2,1); 
surf( data( :, 1:420 )', 'EdgeColor', 'none' ); %//'
title('first 420 columns');
subplot( 1,2,2 );
surf( data( :, 421:end )' ); %//'
title(' remaining columns' );
```

Comment: alternatively the form `surf(X,Y,Z)` with removing the specific column would put it in just one axis.

Comment: data=xlsread('A.xlsx','Sheet1','');
b=data('A2:ACX418,A420:ACX654,A656:ACX703');
plot(b);The 778 columns are named from A through ACX. Where I have gone wrong with this code.Thanks in advance!